# Typescript not narrowing return value of function

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

If I define a function in Typescript that takes a union value and then performs a type check, it isn't narrowing the type for some reason.

Take the following function:

```
const isNumber = (a: number | string) => {
  if (typeof a === "number"){
    return a
  } else {
    return "NaN"
  }
}
```

If I call it and assign it's return value to a variable, Typescript isn't recognizing that its type should be narrowed:

```
let test = isNumber(1) //Hovering over test, Typescript says it's of type string | number.
let test2 = isNumber("Hello") //Again, hovering over test2, Typescript says it's of type string | number.
```

I'm not sure I understand why this is happening, I feel like the return type is obvious based on the parameter type.

Does anyone know how to solve this and/or why Typescript is doing this? While I could assert the return type using `as`, I'm trying to have a consumer of the function not have to assert.

Comment: Put an explicit return type on the function? That'll allow TS to *check* the implementation, rather than assume it's right, too.

Comment: It does appear you're right, if I add `as number` after `let test = isNumber(1)`, then it knows that test equals number. However, this is for a library so I want the user to not have to assert the type after calling the function. I'll update the question to be more specific.

Comment: I don't mean specify the type of the variable you're assigning the return value to, I mean explicitly provide a return type on the function definition.

Comment: How? The return type could be either number or string. We won't know til the function is called.

Comment: Yes it does. I'm not sure why I need to provide a function overload in this instance, as Typescript seems perfectly capable of inferring types in many other situations. Oh well.

Comment: I don't think it can infer overloads; the inferred type is `(a: number | string) => number | "NaN"`. That gets widened to `string | number` because you use `let` not `const` when assigning the return value.